# Hibernate issue with unquoted strategy

Tags: hibernate

Starting from 5.5.3.Final, Hibernate-core changes the *unquotedCaseStrategy* to UPPER (while the original value is MIXED).

```
public class IdentifierHelperBuilder {
    private IdentifierCaseStrategy unquotedCaseStrategy = IdentifierCaseStrategy.UPPER;
    private IdentifierCaseStrategy quotedCaseStrategy = IdentifierCaseStrategy.MIXED;
```

Our project uses following url (with Spring boot) to access the MariaDB. After changing to hibernate-core 5.5.3.Final, our project cannot access the MariaDB correctly. During the investigation, I found that catalog name WebServiceDB will be treated as unquoted and UPPER case WEBSERVICEDB will be used as the catalog (WebServiceDB will be used before hibernate-core 5.5.3.Final) due to the *unquotedCaseStrategy* change.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1:3306/WebServiceDB
```

I want to make the catalog to be **quoted** and use ***quotedCaseStrategy***, following configurations had been tried and did not work. Could you please help me? Thanks a lot.

```
url: jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1:3306/"WebServiceDB"
url: jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1:3306/[WebServiceDB]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to add both globally_quoted_identifiers and globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        globally_quoted_identifiers: true
        globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions: true
```

And following JIRA is opened for this issue.
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15075

In my case, I am using the dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect, and it's legacy configuration.
I need to change to org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect, because our project is using MariaDB 10.4.21.
MariaDBDialect would set unquotedCaseStrategy and quotedCaseStrategy to MIXED.

```
@Override
    public IdentifierHelper buildIdentifierHelper(IdentifierHelperBuilder builder, DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData)
            throws SQLException {

        // some MariaDB drivers does not return case strategy info
        builder.setUnquotedCaseStrategy( IdentifierCaseStrategy.MIXED );
        builder.setQuotedCaseStrategy( IdentifierCaseStrategy.MIXED );

        return super.buildIdentifierHelper( builder, dbMetaData );
    }
```